# Definite numerical integration in a python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of variable number of columns.  I'd like to numerically integrate each column of the dataframe so that I can evaluate the definite integral from row 0 to row 'n'.  I have a function that works on an 1D array, but is there a better way to do this in a pandas dataframe so that I don't have to iterate over columns and cells?  I was thinking of some way of using applymap, but I can't see how to make it work.

This is the function that works on a 1D array:

```
    def findB(x,y):

        y_int = np.zeros(y.size)
        y_int_min = np.zeros(y.size)
        y_int_max = np.zeros(y.size)
        end = y.size-1

       y_int[0]=(y[1]+y[0])/2*(x[1]-x[0])

       for i in range(1,end,1):
            j=i+1
            y_int[i] = (y[j]+y[i])/2*(x[j]-x[i]) + y_int[i-1]

       return y_int
```

I'd like to replace it with something that calculates multiple columns of a dataframe all at once, something like this:

```
    B_df = y_df.applymap(integrator)
```

EDIT:

Starting dataframe dB_df:

```
        Sample1 1 dB    Sample1 2 dB    Sample1 3 dB    Sample1 4 dB Sample1 5 dB   Sample1 6 dB
    0   2.472389    6.524537    0.306852    -6.209527   -6.531123   -4.901795
    1   6.982619    -0.534953   -7.537024   8.301643    7.744730    7.962163
    2   -8.038405   -8.888681   6.856490    -0.052084   0.018511    -4.117407
    3   0.040788    5.622489    3.522841    -8.170495   -7.707704   -6.313693
    4   8.512173    1.896649    -8.831261   6.889746    6.960343    8.236696
    5   -6.234313   -9.908385   4.934738    1.595130    3.116842    -2.078000
    6   -1.998620   3.818398    5.444592    -7.503763   -8.727408   -8.117782
    7   7.884663    3.818398    -8.046873   6.223019    4.646397    6.667921
    8   -5.332267   -9.163214   1.993285    2.144201    4.646397    0.000627
    9   -2.783008   2.288842    5.836786    -8.013618   -7.825365   -8.470759
```

Ending dataframe B_df:

```
        Sample1 1 B Sample1 2 B Sample1 3 B Sample1 4 B Sample1 5 B Sample1 6 B
    0   0.000038    0.000024    -0.000029   0.000008    0.000005    0.000012
    1   0.000034    -0.000014   -0.000032   0.000041    0.000036    0.000028
    2   0.000002    -0.000027   0.000010    0.000008    0.000005    -0.000014
    3   0.000036    0.000003    -0.000011   0.000003    0.000002    -0.000006
    4   0.000045    -0.000029   -0.000027   0.000037    0.000042    0.000018
    5   0.000012    -0.000053   0.000015    0.000014    0.000020    -0.000023
    6   0.000036    -0.000023   0.000004    0.000009    0.000004    -0.000028
    7   0.000046    -0.000044   -0.000020   0.000042    0.000041    -0.000002
    8   0.000013    -0.000071   0.000011    0.000019    0.000028    -0.000036
    9   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

In the above example,

```
    (x[j]-x[i]) = 0.000008
```

Comment: Can you give a example of your input Dataframe and your expected output?

Comment: You are looking for `apply` probably, but this really won't be any more efficient than a loop over the columns.

Comment: Where is `x` coming from? Is it a `Series`, a numpy `ndarray`, or something else?

Comment: x comes from another array, but the ultimately (x[j]-x[i]) is a constant value of 0.000008 for all i and j. @Mad Physicist

Comment: What is the type of `x`? That is much more important than the numerical value.

Comment: May I assume it is a `pd.Series`?

Comment: @Allen, edited post to include dataframes.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, in the function above, `findB()`, `x` and `y` are both `ndarray` .

Comment: I see. If the data comes from a dataframe, it would be much simpler to operate directly on the dataframe.

Comment: If you need to do this with ndarrays, tag your question as numpy.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I can already do it with ndarrays.  I want to know if there is a simpler way to do it in the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can achieve a similar result using vectorized operations. Each element of the integration is just the mean of the current and next `y` value scaled by the corresponding difference in `x`. The final integral is just the cumulative sum of these elements. You can achieve the same result by doing something like

```
def findB(x, y):
    """
    x : pandas.Series
    y : pandas.DataFrame
    """
    mean_y = (y[:-1] + y.shift(-1)[:-1]) / 2
    delta_x = x.shift(-1)[:-1] - x[:-1]
    scaled_int = mean_y.multiply(delta_x)
    cumulative_int = scaled_int.cumsum(axis='index')
    return cumulative_int.shift(1).fillna(0)
```

Here [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) are used to match the indices of the "next" elements to the current. You have to use [`DataFrame.multiply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.multiply.html) rather than the `*` operator to ensure that the proper axis is used (`'index'` vs `'column'`). Finally, [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) provides the final integration step. [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) ensures that you have a first row of zeros as you did in the original solution. The advantage of using all the native pandas functions is that you can pass in a dataframe with any number of columns and have it operate on all of them simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really look for numeric values of the integral? Maybe you just need a **picture**? Then it is easier, using **pyplot**.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Introduce a column *bin* holding left limits of our bins.
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['volume2'], 50).apply(lambda bin: bin.left)
# Group by bins and calculate *f*.
g = df[['bin', 'universe']].groupby('bin').sum()
# Plot the function using cumulative=True.
plt.hist(list(g.index), bins=50, weights=list(g['universe']), cumulative=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]